# cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c11'

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc

I got this error while compiling `cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c11'` a project. All the related issues suggest to use a gcc greater than 4.7 but I already have a gcc greater than 4.7.This is the details

```
gcc version 6.3.0 20170519 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04)
```

I am trying to compile this https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/tree/master/android . Issue is happening in this file https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/blob/master/android/jni/Android.mk while ndk-build.

This is what I am doing

```
-vbox:~/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni$ ndk-build
Compile mips   : ttsespeak <= case.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c11'
make: *** [/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o] Error 1
```

`ndk-build V=1`  command will give the following log.

```
apertium@ap-vbox:~/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni$ ndk-build V=1 
rm -f /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/armeabi/lib*.so /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/mips/lib*.so /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/x86/lib*.so 
rm -f /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/armeabi/gdbserver /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/mips/gdbserver /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/x86/gdbserver 
rm -f /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/mips/gdb.setup /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/libs/x86/gdb.setup 
Compile mips : ttsespeak <= case.c 
/home/apertium/android-ndk-x86/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/mipsel-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o.d -fpic -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-functions -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fmessage-length=0 -fno-inline-functions-called-once -fgcse-after-reload -frerun-cse-after-loop -frename-registers -no-canonical-prefixes -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni/include -I/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni/../../src/ucd-tools/src/include -I/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni/../../src/include -I/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni -DANDROID -std=c11 -DINCLUDE_KLATT -DINCLUDE_SONIC -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I/home/apertium/android-ndk-x86/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-mips/usr/include -c /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/jni/../../src/ucd-tools/src/case.c -o /home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o 
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c11' 
make: *** [/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android/obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o] Error 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compiling how? What commands are you running?

Comment: @muru I am trying to compile this https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/tree/master/android . Issue is happening in this file https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/blob/master/android/jni/Android.mk while ndk-build.

Comment: @muru Can you please check my edit. I don't know how to make it more clear.This error occured while using 'ndk-build' command.

Comment: Where is the MIPS compiler located on your system? What version is it? I'd guess that it's *not* the same version as `/usr/bin/gcc`. Also, which build procedure are you using? `ndk-build` doesn't appear in [`README.md`](https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/blob/master/README.md) at all.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I am following **Android** `make apk-release` is failing with the same error. All the other steps where successfull.`MIPS` is located here `/usr/lib/gcc-cross/mips-linux-gnu`  with version `5` and `5.4.0` available. `gcc` is located in `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu` with version `5,5.4.1,6` and `6.3.0`. How to make both same ?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and how did you install the two GCCs?

Comment: What's the output of `$CC -c -xc -std=c11 -o /dev/null /dev/null` where `$CC` is the path to your MIPS C compiler?

Comment: @DavidFoerster ubuntu is `16.0.4`  and I am using a virtualbox.
Because of the mentioned error I tried to change my gcc using this https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91
and it worked.

I tried your command but got these errors. 

   `-vbox:~/eSpeak/espeak-master# /usr/lib/gcc-cross/mips-linux-gnu/5.4.0/cc1 -c -xc -std=c11 -o /dev/null /dev/null
    cc1: error: command line option ‘-c’ is valid for the driver but not for C
    cc1: error: command line option ‘-xc’ is valid for the driver but not for C `
I dont have cc only have cc1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68813/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-sunil-sunny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of **David Foerster** I found out that the above mentioned error was due to the fact that the Android NDK includes its own C compiler so my NDK was using GCC 4.6 which doesn't support C11. So I [updated my NDK to r16](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#stable-downloads) and resulted in the below error.

```
root@ap-vbox:~/eSpeak/espeak-master# make V=1 apk-release
cd android && ndk-build
/home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python: 10: /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python: 10: /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is higher than android:minSdkVersion 1 in ./AndroidManifest.xml. NDK binaries will *not* be comptible with devices older than android-14. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md for more information.    
/home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python: 10: /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android'
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/* ./libs/armeabi/* ./libs/armeabi-v7a/* ./libs/mips/* ./libs/mips64/* ./libs/x86/* ./libs/x86_64/*
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver ./libs/mips64/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver ./libs/x86_64/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup ./libs/mips64/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
[mips] Compile        : ttsespeak <= case.c
/home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o.d -gcc-toolchain /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -target mipsel-none-linux-android -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes  -g -mips32 -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Ijni/include -Ijni/../../src/ucd-tools/src/include -Ijni/../../src/include -Ijni   -DANDROID -std=c11 -DINCLUDE_KLATT -DINCLUDE_SONIC -D__ANDROID_API__=14 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  --sysroot /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/sysroot -isystem /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/sysroot/usr/include/mipsel-linux-android -c  jni/../../src/ucd-tools/src/case.c -o ./obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o
/home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: 1: /home/apertium/android-ndk-r-16/android-ndk-r16/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
make[1]: *** [obj/local/mips/objs/ttsespeak/__/__/src/ucd-tools/src/case.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/apertium/eSpeak/espeak-master/android'
make: *** [jni] Error 2
```

I was using a virtual box for this. But when I tried to compile the same on an ubuntu installed system there were no issues. Everything went smooth and compiled. So I guess the issue was with my virtual box.